# What is the real native maximum resolution of mid–2010 iMac's iSight camera?

Tags: mac, imovie, quicktime, webcam, photo-booth

I had understood that the pre-2011 Macs & Apple displays have a built–in iSight camera which sensor is capable of VGA (`640 x 480`) resolution—unlike the *FaceTime HD* cameras, which replaced the built–in iSights, that are capable of SXGA (`1280 x 1024`) resolution.

I had also thought that, when importing feed from the camera to an **iMovie**-project, `640 x 480` is the native maximum of the camera and the other, WSVGA (`1024 x 576`), option is upscaled and cropped version of the `640 x 480` feed.

Moreover, when I open **Photo Booth** app, I'm stuck with one resolution which is for video `720 x 480` (DVD (NTSC)) and for pictures `1280 x 853`.

There is still one more native way to record iSight video: **QuickTime Player**—with which the resolutios are as interesting as follows:

- Normal: `640 x 480` (VGA)
- High: `960 x 720`
- Maximum: `1280 x 1024` (SXGA)

This made me suspicious: it says *maximum* but the resolution is over 4 times what I had thought the max was.

Now: **what is the real native maximum resolution that the** (mid–2010 27" iMac's) **built–in iSight camera is capable of?** What is real and what is upscaled?<sup>*</sup>

If there are no *definite & reliable* specifications available, is there a way to confirm it by myself? Judging by  the lack of moiré pattern and other overall fidelity of the SXGA video recorded by QuickTime Player, it seems to me that it is *not* an upscale of the VGA feed.

[Wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISight_Camera) concentrates on the external iSight camera, and while it has a chapter on the built–in version, but, as of today and like the product entries in Wikipedia, it doesn't refer to any working sources.

<sub>*) Upscaled *and cropped* in case of non–4:3 resolutions—the CMOS sensors have almost definitely an aspect ratio of 4:3.</sub>

Comment: Sadly, the IORegistryExplorer doesn't have any device capabilities listed, so the only other tool to grab a raw video stream is [QuartzComposer](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartzcomposer/) (part of Xcode) - It has a nice VideoFeedback.qtz project showing how the apps might use quartz to downsample different camera resolutions to the "standard". Have you read [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2293095?start=0&tstart=0) on speculation why video is down sampled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some [discussion sources](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10688070#10688070) report that using QuickTime video capture at the stated *maximum* quality. That would hint my built-in iSight's resolution is in fact 1280×1024.

Moreover, the iSight upgrade (from 0.3 to 1.3 megapixels) has been noted first at [Mac Daddy World](http://macdaddyworld.com/2007/06/26/new-macbook-pros-new-13-mp-camera-sensor/) and later re-reported at [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/06/27/macbook-pros-feature-a-1-3mp-camera-sensor/) and [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2007/06/28/apple-slides-1-3-megapixel-isight-into-new-macbook-pro/):

- The product ID for the 0.3 MP iSight is `0x8501` and its vendor is `Micron`…
- …while the 1.3 MP iSight's product ID is `0x8502` and the vendor is `Apple`.

Looking at my System information report, I can confirm the product ID is `0x8502`.

So, summa summarum: **mid–2010 iMac's built-in iSight camera has a native resolution of 1280×1024 pixels.**

Answer (score 1):

I think it's 1280x1024, as that's what the LED backlit MacBook Pro's and onwards used. The Lion version of Photo Booth uses the max resolution and crops it.

720x480 is actually a standard resolution - it's what most DVD's use.

Comment: (About the standards: oh yes, I erroneously looked at a non-all-inclusive-list, sorry 'bout that!)